# Calling a webservice through a mobile client

Tags: web-services, rest, cordova, jquery-mobile, soap

I am working with phonegap and jquery mobile at the moment. I just want to know whether there is a library that I can use or a way to call SOAP an RESTful webservices to my mobile client.
I did a lot of research and did not find anything that I can use. Do I need to write this from scratch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First forget about SOAP, at from pure javascript point of view. On the other hand if you are willing you can use Java to create a web service client side code. Next step would be to connect jQuery and native Java part of Phonegap. It can be done easily if you create your own **[plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android)**.

Then again if this is a to much job for you there is also another solution. Same function used for jQuery **`REST`** call can be also used for jQuery **`SOAP`** call. More information can be found in this [**tutorial**](http://leonidius2010.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/98/). But be warned, you will need to write client side XML. Still this is not that great solution.

On the other hand I would rather choose **`REST`** over **`SOAP`**. While **`SOAP`** is great it creates to much data overhead and we need smallest possible data footprint. Because Phonegap is HTML/JS/CSS wrapper it is commonly used to communicate via XHR/Ajax. So in our case it's better to use jQuery Ajax functions. **[Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm)** you can find an excellent tutorial.

One great thing about using $.ajax function inside a Phonegap app for **`REST`** call is that you don't need to worry about **`CROSS-DOMAIN`** calls.

There's also third solution, rather hard but probably best of them all. Instead of using jQuery **$.ajax** function you should think about using Backbone **`MVC`** framework with **`jQuery Mobile`**. It will take time to master this combination but from my experience this is No. 1 solution if you want to use **`REST`** to communicate with your server.